# Alternative to sslSocketFactory in oracle 19c

Tags: spring, web-services, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle19c, sslsocketfactory

I am using OkHttp3 version 4.11.0 and user sslsocketfactory for trust all certificate .But i get error compiling in oracle 19c:

```
create or replace and compile java source named "okhttp" as
package okk;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import okhttp3.*;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable;
import java.lang.*;
import javax.net.ssl.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class OkHttpRequestSender implements HttpRequestSender {

    private static final ObjectMapper mapper;

    static {
        mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    }

    private static final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
            new X509TrustManager() {
                @Override
                public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                }

                @Override
                public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                }

                @Override
                public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[]{};
                }
            }
    };

    private static final SSLContext trustAllSslContext;

    static {
        try {
            trustAllSslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            trustAllSslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyManagementException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private static final SSLSocketFactory trustAllSslSocketFactory = trustAllSslContext.getSocketFactory();

    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(OkHttpRequestSender.class.getName());

    public static OkHttpClient trustAllSslClient(OkHttpClient client) {
      
  
    
      OkHttpClient.Builder builder1 = client.newBuilder();
        builder1.sslSocketFactory( trustAllSslSocketFactory, (X509TrustManager) trustAllCerts[0]);

        builder1.hostnameVerifier((hostname, session) -> true);
        return builder1.build();
    }

    @Override
    public HttpResponse sendPostRequest(@NotNull String url, Object requestBody, @Nullable Map<String, String> headers) {

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
                .connectTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .followRedirects(false)
                .build();

        client = trustAllSslClient(client);

        configureClient(client);

        byte[] sendData;
        if (requestBody instanceof String) {
            sendData = ((String) requestBody).getBytes();
        } else {
            try {
                sendData = mapper.writeValueAsBytes(requestBody);
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("error.in.pars.object.to.json", e);
            }
        }

        RequestBody httpRequestBody = RequestBody.create(sendData, MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"));
        Request.Builder requestBuilder = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .post(httpRequestBody);
        if(headers != null){
            requestBuilder.headers(Headers.of(headers));
        }
        Request request = requestBuilder.build();

        Call call = client.newCall(request);
        HttpResponse response = new HttpResponse();
        try {
            okhttp3.Response okResponse = call.execute();
            ResponseBody responseBody = okResponse.body();
            if(responseBody != null) {
                response.setBody(responseBody.string());
            }

            Map<String, String> responseHeaders = new HashMap<>();
            okResponse.headers().forEach(pair -> {
                responseHeaders.put(pair.component1(), pair.component2());
            });

            response.setHeaders(responseHeaders);
            response.setStatus(okResponse.code());
            return response;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "http request failed with message : {}", e.getMessage());
            if (e instanceof SSLException) {
                response.setStatus(496);
            } else {
                response.setStatus(408);
            }
            return response;
        }
    }

    protected void configureClient(OkHttpClient client) {
    }

    @Override
    public HttpResponse sendGetRequest(@NotNull String url, @Nullable Map<String, String> headers) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Not Implemented");
    }
}
```

i got this error :

error: cannot find symbol

```
  builder.sslSocketFactory( trustAllSslSocketFactory, (X509TrustManager) trustAllCerts[0]);
```

anyone can help me?

when i compiling my code i got error

how can i do to fix this error type

my okhttp3 version is 4.11.0

oracle version is 19c

Comment: Try to check which Java version is user by 19c: `SELECT dbms_java.get_jdk_version JDK_Version FROM dual;`

Comment: There are possible explanations for your problem, either JAVA 8 does not support something in your code, OJVM Java security does not allow you to access certain APIs or you did not use loadjava to load necessary Java classes into OJVM.

Comment: ClassFormatError means that your library was compiled for higher Java version, .. or that particular class PrimitiveSpreadBuilder uses some language construct from Java 9 or higher.